# Linux Mint, Apple Magic Mouse middle scrolling stopped working

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint, magic-mouse

Im using linux mint 18.3. linux kernel 4.15.0-29-generic.

Seemingly randomly a while ago the middle mouse scrolling on my Apple Magic Mouse stopped working. It works on a Mac so I'm sure it's not the mouse

'John Doe’s Mouse' listed below is my mouse.

```
xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ John Doe’s Mouse                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]


xinput --list-props 15
Device 'John Doe’s Mouse':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (284): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (285): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (509):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (510):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (511):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (288): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (289): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (290):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (291):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (292):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (512): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (513): 274
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (296):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (297):    0
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event17"
    Device Product ID (266):    1452, 781
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (300):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (267):    1
```

Do you see anything wrong with the above which could cause this?

edit:

evtest /dev/input/event17 
and then xinput --test

evtest output https://pastebin.com/gTc45Lfy

xinput test output https://pastebin.com/7VyWAmAd

i noticed when i was middle scrolling, no new events would show up

Comment: Have you tried in another computer?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It works on a Mac so I'm sure it's not the mouse

Comment: Please [edit] and add that information. Otherwise everybody else will suspect hardware failure as I did.

Comment: The way to debug this is to first use `evtest /dev/input/event17` (with the current number, may change between boots) and then `xinput --test 15` (with the current number), and look if you get events for middle mouse scrolling, and if yes, which events. That will tell you where to look for a wrong configuration.

Comment: @dirkt No command 'evest' found,

Comment: Sorry, `evtest`.

Comment: @dirkt added output to the first post

Comment: You are getting normal mouse movement instead of scrolling (unless you did mouse movement during the test). Next thing to try is to use `xinput set-prop ...` to activate the various scrolling methods. Start with `xinput set-prop 15 291 0 0 1`, verify with `--list-props`, see if anything changed. Then 286 (natural scrolling), then disable 291 again.

Comment: Oh, and the "seeming randomly a while ago" is probably correlated to when you upgraded your system and changed to libinput from whatever you used before.

Comment: @dirkt output here https://pastebin.com/MssTNiHw it didn't seem to like 286

Comment: `xinput set-prop 15 286 1` of course - compare with the value in `--list-props`.

Comment: And the idea is to test each of these, in all combinations.

Comment: output for that https://pastebin.com/cg9wh2Ua

im not sure i want to mess too much with it since i dont understand what 0, 0, 1 etc means?

Comment: also is reboot needed to apply each change or not?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing a workaround of changing

libinput Button Scrolling Button (512): 2

> > xinput set-prop 15 512 3

So that when i hold the right click button and move the mouse it scrolls. Not ideal but it works